# can not open jmeter no-gui from shell script

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to rum jmeter from a shell script but its giving me error:

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/dynamicJmeter.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[8]/com.blazemeter.jmeter.RandomCSVDataSetConfig
line number         : 1309
version             : 4.0 r1823414
-------------------------------
```

I have installed the plugin manager and udp support plugin in jmeter but still the command doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md) plugin which is referenced in your .jmx test script and not installed on the JMeter instance where you're trying to open this file.

So make sure to install the plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Random CSV Data Set]

and restart JMeter afterwards to pick up the plugin.

Just in case check out Introducing the [Random CSV Data Set Config Plugin on JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter) article for comprehensive plugin installation and usage instructions